# ListView only shows one item and overwrites item when button is pressed, need to continuously add items based on measurements

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview

I replaced a TextView that continuously adds test results when a button is pressed in my app with a ListView.  For each button press, I want the ListView to add an item.  Each time I press the button, item 1 in the listview is overwritten.  I am not using a scrollview with my listview.

I originally thought it was because the string I am placing into the ListView was not declared as a string array. I duplicated the array with a string array and added some dummy data but my ArrayList does not except string arrays.  It seems like I'm in a catch-22.

I'm not sure why I'm getting downvoted.  I researched this thoroughly and every attempt I've tried has come from examples and other questions.  If someone can at least tell me why this is a bad question and doesn't contribute to anything I would appreciate it.

I think my problem is with the ArrayAdapter and I've tried every suggestion I've seen on stackoverflow and anywhere else but I can't fix the problem.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

The key difference between my question and similar questions about this topic that the by pressing the button, new data is written to the string based on measurements taken from the Bluetooth device including date, GPS coordinates, and others.  It is not a string array that is already predefined.

All of the code from .java file can't fit in the question.  I'll post the the code relevant for this problem including commented out code from when the listview was a textview.

ScannerFragment.java:

```
 private ListView mReadingLog;
 mReadingLog  = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.scanLogView);
    //mReadingLog.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());//8/31
    //mReadingLog.setText(readFromFile());//8/31
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        // Get local Bluetooth adapter
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        // If the adapter is null, then Bluetooth is not supported
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            activity.finish();
        }

        if(shouldAskPermission()) {
            if(!permissionGranted) {
                requestPermissions(perms, permsRequestCode);
            }
        }
    }
```

later on...

```
 public void readIris(String readMessage) {
        if(!readoutStarted) {
            return;
        }

        String parsedData[];

        if(readMessage.contains(";")) {
            readoutStarted = false;
            if(readMessage.equals(";")) {
                parsedData = bufferedMessage.replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll(" +", " ").trim().split("\\*");
                bufferedMessage = "";
            } else {
                String partialMessage[] = readMessage.replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll(" +", " ").trim().split(";");
                bufferedMessage += partialMessage[0].trim();
                parsedData = bufferedMessage.replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll(" +", " ").trim().split("\\*");
                bufferedMessage = "";
            }
        } else {
            bufferedMessage += readMessage.trim().replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll(" +", " ");
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, Arrays.toString(parsedData));

        boolean passed = false;
        int v1 = 0;
        int v2 = 0;
        if(parsedData[3].equals("S")) {
            passed = true;
            String values[] = parsedData[7].split("\\s+");
            v1 = Integer.parseInt(values[0].replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
            v2 = Integer.parseInt(values[values.length-1]);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, Arrays.toString(parsedData));
            String values[] = parsedData[5].split("\\s+");
            v1 = Integer.parseInt(values[0].replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
            v2 = Integer.parseInt(values[values.length-1]);
        }
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());

        String saveData =
                "Device: " + mConnectedDeviceName +
                        System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                        "Timestamp: " + currentDateandTime +
                        System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                        "Location: " + latitude + " (lat) / " + longitude + " (lon)" +
                        System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                        "Phone id: "  + telephonyManager.getDeviceId() +
                        System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                        "Valid:" + (passed ? "YES" : "NO") +
                        System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                        "Values: " + "T" + v1 + " / " + v2 +
                        System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                        "=========================" +
                        System.getProperty("line.separator");

      String saveData2 =  "Device: " + mConnectedDeviceName +
                        System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                        "Timestamp: " + currentDateandTime +
                        System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                        "Location: " + latitude + " (lat) / " + longitude + " (lon)" +
                        System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                        "Phone id: "  + telephonyManager.getDeviceId() +
                        System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                        "Valid:" + (passed ? "YES" : "NO") +
                        System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                        "Values: " + "T" + v1 + " / " + v2 +
                        System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                        //"=========================" + //8/31/17
                        System.getProperty("line.separator");


        String csvData = mConnectedDeviceName + "," +
                currentDateandTime + "," +
                "\"http://maps.google.com/?q=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "\"," +
                "Valid: " + (passed ? "YES" : "NO") + " - " + "T" + v1 + " / " + v2 + Integer.toString(savedTaggantType) + "," +
                "\"" + telephonyManager.getDeviceId() + "\"" +
                System.getProperty("line.separator");


        ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>(); //8/31/17
        listItems.add(saveData2.toString()); //8/31/17
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, listItems); //8/31
        mReadingLog.setAdapter(adapter);  //8/31
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      // mReadingLog.setText(saveData + mReadingLog.getText()); 8/31/17
        mShowData.setText(saveData); //kg 8/25/17

        if(SP.getBoolean("writeToFile", true)) {
            writeToFile(saveData, csvData, true);
        }
    }
```

view_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:id="@+id/viewList"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:visibility="visible">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/button_holder"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/flipperReturn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Return"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_clear_log"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/clear_log"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/listview_holder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/button_holder"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/scanLogView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:divider="@android:color/black"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
                android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
                android:maxLines="4096"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_bluetooth_scanner.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:weightSum="1">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_connect"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:text="@string/connect" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_disconnect"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/disconnect" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_poweroff"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/poweroff" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#ccc"/>




    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#ccc"/>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/layoutContainer" android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/batimg"
                android:src="@drawable/battery" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left">

            <ProgressBar
                style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:progress="0"
                android:id="@+id/progressBar" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:ems="10"
                android:text="N/A%"
                android:textSize="@dimen/margin_medium"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:id="@+id/label_batterypct" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.35"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left">


            <View
                android:layout_marginLeft="5pt"
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="#ccc"/>


            <Button
                android:layout_marginLeft="10pt"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="10pt"
                android:background="#ff2b0f"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:text="OFFLINE"
                android:id="@+id/button_connectionblink"
                />

            <Button
                android:layout_marginLeft="10pt"
                android:layout_marginTop="12pt"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="10pt"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:background="#cccccc"
                android:text="DATA"
                android:id="@+id/button_communication"
                />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.30"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left">


            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="#ccc"/>


            <Button
                android:layout_marginLeft="5pt"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="10pt"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:text="NAME"
                android:id="@+id/button_devicename"
                />

            <Button
                android:layout_marginLeft="5pt"
                android:layout_marginTop="12pt"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="10pt"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:text="S/N"
                android:id="@+id/button_devicesn"
                />



        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:background="#ccc"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_small"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">


        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:layout_height="80pt"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:background="#ffc4ab"
            android:text="NO TAGGANT DETECTED"
            android:id="@+id/button_present"
            />



    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/viewLog"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="View Log"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:layout_above="@id/viewLog"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />


    </RelativeLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

There are other files included in the project that I didn't think were relevant to the question but I am new to android programming and I just inherited this project so if I am missing important information please let me know!

I tried changing things at the end of the readIris() function.  I changed saveData2 to a string array and added a list and used.add to add a different string.  It not adds two items but overwrites both with the same data.  How do I continuously add array entries and then add those to a listview each time the button is hit?

from readIris:

```
    String saveData =
            "Device: " + mConnectedDeviceName +
                    System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                    "Timestamp: " + currentDateandTime +
                    System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                    "Location: " + latitude + " (lat) / " + longitude + " (lon)" +
                    System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                    "Phone id: "  + telephonyManager.getDeviceId() +
                    System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                    "Valid:" + (passed ? "YES" : "NO") +
                    System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                    "Values: " + "T" + v1 + " / " + v2 +
                    System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                    "=========================" +
                    System.getProperty("line.separator");

  String[] saveData2 = new String[]{  "Device: " + mConnectedDeviceName +
                    System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                    "Timestamp: " + currentDateandTime +
                    System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                    "Location: " + latitude + " (lat) / " + longitude + " (lon)" +
                    System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                    "Phone id: "  + telephonyManager.getDeviceId() +
                    System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                    "Valid:" + (passed ? "YES" : "NO") +
                    System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                    "Values: " + "T" + v1 + " / " + v2 +
                    System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                    //"=========================" + //8/31/17
                    System.getProperty("line.separator")
  };


    String csvData = mConnectedDeviceName + "," +
            currentDateandTime + "," +
            "\"http://maps.google.com/?q=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "\"," +
            "Valid: " + (passed ? "YES" : "NO") + " - " + "T" + v1 + " / " + v2 + Integer.toString(savedTaggantType) + "," +
            "\"" + telephonyManager.getDeviceId() + "\"" +
            System.getProperty("line.separator");

    final List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(saveData2));
    /*ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>(); //8/31/17
    listItems.add(saveData2.toString()); //8/31/17*/
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, dataList); //8/31
    mReadingLog.setAdapter(adapter);  //8/31
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  // mReadingLog.setText(saveData + mReadingLog.getText()); 8/31/17
    mShowData.setText(saveData); //kg 8/25/17
    dataList.add(saveData);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a proper answer but my app is now doing what I want it to do.  Because I can't fit the entire file, I'll try to be clear on where I implemented the changes without making everything confusing.

First, in ScannerFragment.java I made the following decorations:

```
int clickCounter = 0;
ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>(); //9/11/17
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter; //9/11/17
```

Then in the same java file in the onViewCreated() function I wired the listview with this:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, listItems); //9/11/17
        mReadingLog.setAdapter(adapter);  //9/11/17
```

Then later on in the readIris() function in the same file I add information to the list and notify the adapter that it is updated:

```
listItems.add(
                "Device: " + mConnectedDeviceName +
                        System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                        "Timestamp: " + currentDateandTime +
                        System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                        "Location: " + latitude + " (lat) / " + longitude + " (lon)" +
                        System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                        "Phone id: "  + telephonyManager.getDeviceId() +
                        System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                        "Valid:" + (passed ? "YES" : "NO") +
                        System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                        "Values: " + "T" + v1 + " / " + v2 +
                        System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                       // "=========================" +
                        System.getProperty("line.separator") );//9/11/17
        clickCounter++;//9/11/17
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//9/11/17
```

I hope this can help someone else at some point because it was a real pain to figure out.  I think the following answer summarizes how to use a button to add text to a listview in a general sense:

1. Have an xml file with a button and listview:

   ```
   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_small"
       android:paddingLeft="4dp"
       android:paddingRight="4dp"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">


       <Button
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight=".3"
           android:layout_height="80pt"
           android:padding="12dp"
           android:clickable="false"
           android:textSize="12dp"
           android:background="#ffc4ab"
           android:text="text"
           android:id="@+id/button_present"
           />
   ```
2. Declare variables for listview, button, arrayadapters, and others in your java class:

   ```
   private Button mPresence;
   private ListView mReadingLog;

   int clickCounter = 0;
   ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>(); //9/11/17
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter; //9/11/17
   ```
3. Create a function that links the java and xml code that runs one time, like onCreate or onViewCreated and wire your pieces together:

   ```
   mReadingLog  = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.scanLogView);
   //mReadingLog.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());//8/31
   //mReadingLog.setText(readFromFile());//8/31

   adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, listItems); //9/11/17
   mReadingLog.setAdapter(adapter);  //9/11/17
   mPresence = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_present);
   ```
4. Update the arraylist and arrayadapter when the button is pressed:

   ```
    mPresence.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener)({
    @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
       listItems.add("your text");//9/11/17
       clickCounter++;//9/11/17
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//9/11/17}
   ```